# Why doesn't List.Contains work as I expect?

Tags: c#

Why does this program print "not added" while I think it should print "added"?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Element
{
    public int id;

    public Element(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static implicit operator Element(int d)  
    {
        Element ret = new Element(d);
        return ret;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Element e1, Element e2)
    {
        return (e1.id == e2.id);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Element e1, Element e2)
    {
        return !(e1.id == e2.id);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Element> element = new List<Element>();
        element.Add(2);
        if(element.Contains(2))
            Console.WriteLine("added");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("not added");
    }
}
```

The `Contains` method does not use the `==` operator‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you forget implementing Equals and GetHashCode?

Comment: Not worth the headache of using List.Contains use LINQ Where/First/Single

Comment: +1 for complete example code demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> The Contains method does not use the == operator‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

No - it uses `Equals`, which you haven't overridden... so you're getting the default behaviour of `Equals`, which is to check for reference identity instead. You should override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` to be consistent with each other - and for sanity's sake, consistent with your `==` overload too.

I'd also recommend implementing `IEquatable<Element>`, which `List<Element>` will use in preference to `Equals(object)`, as `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` picks it up appropriately.

Oh, and your operator overloads should handle null references, too.

I'd also *strongly* recommend using private fields instead of public ones, and making your type immutable - seal it and make `id` readonly. Implementing equality for mutable types can lead to odd situations. For example:

```
Dictionary<Element, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<Element, string>();
Element x = new Element(10);
dictionary[x] = "foo";
x.id = 100;
Console.WriteLine(dictionary[x]); // No such element!
```

This would happen because the hash code would change (at least under most implementations), so the hash table underlying the dictionary wouldn't be able to find even a reference to the *same* object that's already in there.

So your class would look something like this:

```
internal sealed class Element : IEquatable<Element>
{
    private readonly int id;

    public int Id { get { return id; } }

    public Element(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static implicit operator Element(int d)  
    {
        return new Element(d);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Element e1, Element e2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(e1, e2))
        {
            return true; 
        }
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(e1, null) ||
            object.ReferenceEquals(e2, null))
        {
            return false; 
        }
        return e1.id == e2.id;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Element e1, Element e2)
    {
        // Delegate...
        return !(e1 == e2);
    }

    public bool Equals(Element other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // Delegate...
        return Equals(obj as Element);
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure about the merit of the implicit conversion, by the way - I typically stay away from those, myself.)

Comment: The assumption is that the `id` uniquely identifies the object.  This is certainly very common, but there are situations (e.g. Entity Framework) where the id may be initially set to 0 until an ID is later assigned (e.g. when the object is persisted).  I'm not sure that Equals would be meaningful in that context, but if that is a possibility for the OP, it needs to be accounted for.

Comment: +1 for explaining the weird side effects of mutating an object that is used in a dictionary or other place where hash code is used.

Comment: I don't like using `IEquatable<T>` for non-sealed types.  Even if one implements `IEquatable<T>`, one would still need to override `Equals(Object)` for semantic correctness; unless `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` chains to `Equals(Object)` [in which case the interface would serve no purpose] it will be very hard for derived classes to define any new equality-related criteria.  BTW, I also don't like overloading `==` on reference types.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed on sealing - that's why I made the class sealed as well. Unfortunately an edit at roughly the same time removed my sample code... For overloading `==`, I'm on the fence - I'm very glad it *is* overloaded for `==`, for example, but it can certainly be overdone.

Comment: The `Equals(object obj)` method should be returning `Equals(obj as Element)`. That aside, I'm not sure I like this approach of `Equals(Element other)`: the use of `other != null` uses the overloaded operator, not the built-in reference inequality operator, and if you're going to use the overloaded operator already, can you not simply use `return this == other;` there?

Comment: @hvd: Whoops, fixed for the first part. And yes, changed to `this == other;` - aside from anything else, all the logic is now in a single place.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't think your sample code was there when I wrote the comment.  As for `==`, a big objection I have to overloading it is that C# uses same token is used for its overloadable equality and non-overloadable reference-equivalence operators (unlike e.g. VB, which uses `Is` for reference equivalence), so a class should only override `==` if code is unlikely to be interested in reference equivalence.  If the equality-check operator would only compile when overloaded (as in VB) I'd favor overloading in more situations.

Comment: @supercat: No, the code wasn't there when you wrote the comment - it had been earlier, but it had been removed by another editor, accidentally :( I'd be happy with a `===` operator which always meant reference equality, and which didn't exist for value types...

Answer (score 13):

> The Contains method does not use the == operator‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌. What is the problem?

That is correct.

> This method [Contains] determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to override Equals() as well.  Note when you overload Equals(), it is almost always correct to also override GetHashCode().

Answer (score 11):

Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like:

```
class Element
{
    public int id;

    protected bool Equals(Element other)
    {
        return id == other.id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Element) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id; //or id.GetHashCode();
    }
 //..... rest of the class
```

See: [`List<T>.Contains Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method determines equality by using the default equality
>   comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the
>   `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method for T (the type of values in the list).

Comment: Thank you. Your code simplified my work. If it was possible I would accept your answer too.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus, you accepted the right answer. Don't think about accepting my answer against Jon Skeet's, or I will be atomized :P