# How to check if list contains item

Tags: c#, list, uwp

I want to add list item only when it is not listed. Here is my code

```
public static void addItem()
{
    var item = new Car {Make = Ford, Model = Explorer};
    if(myList.Contains(item) == false)
    {
        myList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It works, but if statement always return `false`
Thanks for help

Comment: Override `Equals` (and as bonus `GetHashCode`)

Comment: Fyi, the duplicate mentions the overloading of the `==` operator and uses that also in `Equals`. That's a bit misleading(but OP had tried to do that). It's not necessary if you want to override `Equals`. Just put your logic there, for example `return Make==other.Make && Model==other.Model`. [There's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26472791/284240) also a simple example.